# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Epidemie und Seuche?

Tags: difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Epidemie und Seuche? Sind sie in den meisten Situationen Synonyme?

Answer (score 8):

Das eine ist ein Lehnwort, das andere ein deutsches Wort. Beide Begriffe bezeichnen annähernd dasselbe.

Das Wort *»Seuche«* ist mit dem Verb *»siechen«* verwandt, welches nichts anderes als *»krank sein«* bedeutet, aber veraltet ist. *»Seuche«* und *»siechen«* stammen vom alhochdeutschen *»siuhhī«* ab, was *»Krankheit«* bedeutet. Eine Seuche ist aber nicht einfach nur eine Krankheit, sondern eine ansteckende Krankheit, die viele Individuen befällt. (Beispiel: Lungenkrebs ist eine Krankheit, aber keine Seuche, weil Lungenkrebs nicht ansteckend ist. Panleukopenie ist eine Seuche, denn das ist eine ansteckende Infektionskrankheit die Katzen befällt.)

Das Wort *»Epidemie«* wurde im 18. Jahrhundert aus dem lateinischen *»epidemia«* entlehnt, das selbst wiederum griechische Wurzeln hat, nämlich ἐπί (epí) (»auf, bei, dazu«) und δῆμος (dēmos) (»Volk«).

Eine Epidemie befällt viele Menschen, bedroht aber nicht alle Menschen auf dem Planeten. Wenn das der Fall ist, spricht man von einer Pandemie. Das Wort *»Seuche«* kann auf beide Szenarien angewendet werden.

---

Ergänzung nach kurzer Diskussion in den Kommentaren:

Die Bezeichnung *»Epidemie«* (oder *»Pandemie«*) wird auf einen Krankheitsausbruch bei einer großen Zahl von Erkrankten angewendet, der mitunter in mehreren Wellen verlaufen kann. Epidemien sind zeitlich begrenzte Ereignisse. Den Begriff *»Seuche«* verwendet man für eine Krankheit, die solche Ausbruchswellen hervorbringen kann.

Die Pocken bezeichnet man auch heute noch als Seuche, obwohl - dank Durchimpfung der Gesamtbevölkerung - niemand mehr daran erkrankt und es keine Pocken-Epidemien mehr gibt.

Comment: Gute Antwort! Vielleicht gibt es aber doch Nuancen. Würdest Du z.B. die Pest als Seuche bezeichnen, auch wenn sie heutzutage nicht mehr als Epidemie auftritt, aber weltweit immerhin noch ca. 3000 Menschen jährlich daran erkranken? Ich bin mir darüber nicht im Klaren.

Comment: @PaulFrost Es gibt durchaus noch Pestepidemien, z. B. [2017/2018 in Madagaskar](https://www.who.int/emergencies/disease-outbreak-news/item/27-november-2017-plague-madagascar-en). Die Pest ist in Madagaskar endemisch, und besonders große und/oder sich schnell ausbreitende Ausbrüche werden als Epidemie eingestuft. Siehe z. B. [DLF](https://www.deutschlandfunk.de/pestausbruch-in-madagaskar-epidemische-ausbreitung-der.676.de.html?dram:article_id=408164) oder [Tagesspiegel](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/wissen/schwarzer-tod-pest-in-madagaskar-chronik-einer-epidemie/20462514.html).

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Dass es auch noch (kleinere) epidemische Pestausbrüche gibt, glaube ich gerne. Mein Kommentar bezog sich auf den Wortsinn: Ich halte es für zulässig, zu sagen "Die Pest ist eine Seuche" - auch wenn aktuell niemand daran erkrankt ist. "Die Pest ist eine Epidemie" würde ich unter diesen Umständen nicht sagen.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Ich glaube, du hast recht. Epidemien sind Krankheitsausbrüche. Die Krankheiten selbst werden nicht *Epidemien* sondern *Seuchen* genannt. Ich habe meine Antwort entsprechend ergänzt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das Verhältnis zwischen *Seuche* und *Epidemie* ist wirklich subtil. Mir scheint, dass eine Krankheit erst dann als Seuche bezeichnet wird, wenn sie (1) infektiös ist und (2) es irgendwann einmal einen schlimmen epidemischen Ausbruch gab (oder es sogar früher *immer wieder* Epidemien gab). Außerdem muss die Krankheit eine hohe Sterblichkeit verursachen oder gravierende "Dauerschäden" nach sich ziehen (wie Polio).  Einen Schnupfen würde man m.E. nicht als Seuche bezeichnen.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Du könntest deine Erkenntnisse ja in eine Antwort verpacken anstatt sie als Kommentar unter eine andere Antwort zu schreiben.